# i cant see it but is something wrong with'{this.props.promotions.filter(promotion=>promotion.featoured)[0]}'it keeps saying can't access property

Tags: reactjs

I can't really see it but is there something wrong with
`promotion={this.props.promotions.filter(promotion=>promotion.featured)[0]}`

I keep getting this error, and I'm having trouble figuring it out:

> TypeError: can't access property "filter", this.props.promotion is undefined. its suposed to me filtering an object in props.its so the state from promotions is sent i think

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './HomeComponent';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Directory from './DirectoryComponent';
import CampsiteInfo from './CampsiteInfoComponent';
import Header from './HeaderComponent';
import Footer from './FooterComponent';
import Contact from './ContactComponent';
import About from './AboutComponent';
import { addComment } from '../redux/ActionCreators';


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        campsites: state.campsites,
        comments: state.comments,
        partners: state.partners,
        promotion: state.promotion
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    addComment: (campsiteId, rating, author, text) => (addComment(campsiteId, rating, author, text))
};
class Main extends Component {
    
    render() {
        const HomePage = () => {
            return (
                <Home
                    campsite={this.props.campsites.campsites.filter(campsite=>campsite.featured)[0]}
                    
                    promotion={this.props.promotions.promotions.filter(promotions=>promotions.featured)[0]}
                    partner={this.props.partners.partners.filter(partners=> partners.featured)[0]}
                />
            );
        };
        const CampsiteWithId = ({match}) => {
            return (
                <CampsiteInfo 
                    campsite={this.props.campsites.filter(campsite=> campsite.id === +match.params.campsiteId)[0]}
                    comments={this.props.comments.filter(comment => comment.campsiteId === +match.params.campsiteId)}
                    addComment={this.props.addComment}
                />
            );
        }; 
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/home' component={HomePage} />
                    <Route exact path='/directory' render={()=> <Directory campsites={this.props.campsites} />} />
                    <Route path='/directory/:campsiteId' component={CampsiteWithId} />
                    <Route exact path='/contactus' component={Contact} />
                    <Route exact path='/aboutus' render={()=> <About partners={this.props.partners} />} />
                    <Redirect to='/home' />
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main));
```

Comment: i used 'promotion={this.props.promotions.promotions.filter(promotions=>promotions.featured)[0]}' and the same error comes up

Comment: The error "TypeError: can't access property "filter", this.props.promotion is undefined" means that `this.props.promotion` is undefined. Check that it's actually being set by whatever is rendering it.

Comment: so like nconsole.log(Main.promotions);

Comment: it think this is rendering it `ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);`

Comment: can u add more code

Comment: heres the whole file

Comment: what is features, and what do you want to do using `.filter`

Comment: just to pass promotions state to store

Comment: can u add data that u are passing? That will give an ide about the structure of the props

Comment: i think its being rendered `ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);`

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if props dont have `promotions` in the initial render. Do some validation like below. Do similar validations for `campsite` and `partners` if needed.

```
<Home
  campsite={
    this.props.campsites.campsites.filter((campsite) => campsite.featured)[0]
  }
  promotion={
    this.props.promotions &&
    Array.isArray(this.props.promotions.promotions) &&
    this.props.promotions.promotions.length
      ? this.props.promotions.promotions.filter(
          (promotions) => promotions.featured
        )[0]
      : ""
  }
  partner={
    this.props.partners.partners.filter((partners) => partners.featured)[0]
  }
/>;
```

Comment: whats the array.isarrat for i thought you dont need that if your just passing the promotions state to the store

Comment: `Array.isArray` is to check if your variable is an Array. `filter` can be applied only to an array.

Comment: o i thought when you filter out something it creates an array

Comment: id do that for campsites and partners too right since those lines are doing the same thing

Comment: Yes, add it and check

Comment: it didnt work it just messed up other parts of it

Comment: is there something like that but with objects that might work better since most of this is working with objects